How can I speed up HTTP post requests?
I'm making a REST API for college class schedules and inserting the data into the database is taking forever. My program works by downloading a PDF schedule from my university's website, stripping its text and printing it to a text file, then parsing the text file for course details. Everything is fully functional, it just isn't efficient.
After course details are found, a Course object is created from the rest model class and gets stored in a list.
public class Parser {
    private static List<Course> courses;

    public static void parse(File file) {
        [collecting data...]

        Course course = new Course(crn, subject, number, title, department, hours, instructor, size, seats, semester, term);
        courses.add(course);
    }

    public static List<Course> getCourses() {
        return courses;
    }
}

Once all the courses are found, this method is called to put them in the database. It takes ~3 minutes to load 15,000 courses.
/** Constructs a JSON request body and posts course data to the server. */
public static void saveCourses(List<Course> courses) throws URISyntaxException, IOException, InterruptedException {
    for (int i = 0; i < courses.size(); i++) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(courses.get(i));
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
        HttpRequest httpRequest = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
            .uri(new URI("http://localhost:8080/course/save"))
            .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .POST(BodyPublishers.ofString(json))
            .build();
        httpClient.send(httpRequest, BodyHandlers.ofString());
    }
}

I'm not sure if it's the toJson() call or the actual request that's taking so long, but what can I do to make my program faster?

Start with a profiler to find where is the bottleneck. It could be anything from the database to slow internet connection. But the 1st thing to do is move gson out of the loop - you are currently creating and garbage collecting 15000 instances of gson, when you should be using only 1.

3 minutes for 15'000 requests, that's about 12ms per request. It's not that bad.

No need to create the HttpClient inside the loop either.

Why is 3 minutes a problem? Doesn't this just happen once?

Are you constrained to a 1:1 calls ? Can you add a bulk API receiving a list of JSON objects ? Can you send dem requests concurrently ?

Yes. To summarize, the problem is not that much that the processing on the server is inefficient, but that you are doing a lot of requests. I see two approaches to deal with that:

The first, that would not require any modification on the server side would be to use asynchronous requests. If your server cannot support 15'000 concurrent requests, then use batches of 100 or 1000 requests.
The other approach consists in adding to your server a method to post a list of Courses instead of a single one, and send the whole list in a single request, or, again, in batches. In the latter case, you can try to optimize further by using asynchronous requests.

